# unable to store the data from from tweet api V2 to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, tweepy, mongodb-atlas, twitter-api-v2

currently I'm doing my project on tweet feed analysis using Tweet API v2 and storing it in mongodb.
I need to fetch data from tweet API v2 and store it in mongodb, i took tweepylistener class which is for API V1.1 and replaced StreamingClient, but that class doesn't save collection to the mongodb database

i had seen many references and tutorial, nothing works for Twitter API V2, so help me with the solution of class to store the collection from twitter API V2 to mongodb DataBase

here is my code..

```
class TweepyListener(tweepy.StreamingClient) : 
    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        print(tweet.id) 
        try : 
            tweet_collection. insert_one( tweet ._json) 
        except : 
            pass 
    def on_error(self, tweet_code) : 
        if status_code == 420:
            return False
        
my_stream = TweepyListener("Bearer Token Here") 
my_stream.sample()
```

I tried taking the tweetlistener class for API V1.1 and change it for V2 and checked but it doesn't work

Comment: That extra space before `insert_one` could be causing an error.  Perhaps log the error instead of pass

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.